# Trouble setting up SSH via ethernet

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, ubuntu

As the title suggests im trying to set up SSH access to my pi 3 B+ and running into a few issues.
pc running Ubuntu 19.10 is plugged into RPi however no connection is being made, thus i cant set up the wired connection on my PC end.

Is this a frequent issue? / does anyone know an alternative method for setting up the ethernet SSH

Comment: The SSH server does not care if the connection is via WiFi or wired. Did you put the ssh file in /boot on the SD card before booting?  If not add it in and boot the Pi again.  Can you ping the Pi by IP address?  Can you ping the Pi by name?

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable ssh; sudo systemctl start ssh` will fix it for the next boot and start it now.

Comment: Does the leds on the wired port of the RasPi are light and flashing?